# Linux socket is not using the src-ip from the bind address

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, sockets

I have a single Linux machine with 3 interfaces, eth0, host1, and loopback. And I have an application that sends out packets at the loopback and routed out to host1. To achieve this, my application creates a client socket that binds to an address "5.6.7.8" which is a loopback interface. (The bind was successful and verified by "getsockname" api). Here goes the loopback cfg:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 5.6.7.8/32 scope global lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And the application sends a packet out to destination IP (1.2.3.4) which will be routed through host1.

```
# ip route
default via 16.254.1.1 dev eth0
1.2.3.4 dev host1 scope link
16.254.1.1 dev eth0 scope link

# ip route get 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4 dev host1 src 20.0.1.1 uid 0
    cache

# ifconfig host1
host1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 20.0.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    ether da:3f:23:ff:f2:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 105  bytes 8858 (8.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6017  bytes 280258 (273.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So I'd expect packets from my application will use the source IP of 5.6.7.8, but when I capture the packet through tcpdump, it's source IP is actually using 20.0.1.1 which is from host1. I checked the iptables and no NAT rules installed. Does anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: I suggest you run `tcpdump` on `host1` on both the `ingress` & `egress` interfaces and compare. Your use of arbitrary IP  addresses does not make things clear, but I assume all hosts are visible directly on the internet and are not using private address space.

Comment: Does the bind() call actually succeed? Does netstat/ss show the correct address? Do you have any NAT (masquerade) iptables rules?

Comment: bind() call was successful and verified with "getsockname" to check if it is correctly bound. When I see netstat, it shows the address 20.0.1.1 which is invalid, but matches up with the observation from tcpdump (src-ip being 20.0.1.1). I checked iptables NAT, MANGLE, FILTER, RAW also checked nft tables and nothing.

Comment: The info you are giving us is chaotic. You're not telling us the layout, nor are you telling us where those addresses are seen. Do not drip feed information.

Comment: Since it's the same box, then it does not matter what you see, the kernel will choose the most obliging interface and route, hence the specific source IP address.